# How do I efficiently close the buffer opened by `slime-describe-symbol`?

Tags: emacs, slime, spacemacs

The issue:

1. I have started a Common Lisp session with a `*slime-repl sbcl*` in its default vertical split.
2. I am on a symbol, let's say `cond`, and press the key for `slime-describe-symbol` which in my case is `,hh` as I am using spacemacs.
3. This opens a buffer `*slime-description*` on top of the repl window.

I am now left in a situation where I have to:

- move to the split on the right
- switch buffer to the slime `*slime-repl sbcl*`
- return to my original buffer

I have to do this every time I open a help file which seems strange as the designed workflow. I would expect this to be possible using a single keystroke.

What is the intended way of managing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain emacs the keyboard shortcut for moving to the other window is 'C-x o' (other window). I'd assume the easiest way to achieve the automatic cursor movement when describing a symbol would be to define your own custom elisp function by modifying slime-describe-symbol to move the cursor to the *slime-description* window and (re)bind the keyboard shortcut.

On my machine:

`` (defun my-slime-describe-symbol (symbol-name)
  "Describe the symbol at point."
  (interactive (list (slime-read-symbol-name "Describe symbol: ")))
  (when (not symbol-name)
    (error "No symbol given"))
  (slime-eval-describe `(swank:describe-symbol ,symbol-name))
  (switch-to-buffer-other-window "*slime-description*")) ``

and then define the keyboard shortcut to your liking:

`(define-key slime-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-d d") 'my-slime-describe-symbol)
 (define-key slime-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-d C-d") 'my-slime-describe-symbol)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer Orm :) I am afraid this is not what I am trying to achieve. I have rephrased my question to make it more clear. I am mainly looking for the default way of doing this though if I can't find the answer I will have to create a custom function in which case your current answer will come in handy.

Comment: Are you aware that once in the *slime-description* buffer, simply pressing 'q' will close the buffer and get you back to where you initiated the slime-describe-symbol command?

Comment: Yes indeed, but the usual pattern is that when the description buffer is opened, emacs moves the cursor to it. In my case the description buffer opens but the cursor remains on the original file which means that I have to manually move to it and close it. Maybe it is a `spacemacs` bug.. I guess another solution would be opening `slime-description` on the same buffer so that I can close it and return to the original.

Comment: I don't think it is spacemacs as this happens on my machine as well. That's why I wrote the function above. It should solve this problem. If the keyboard shortcut doesn't work, try it first with M-x my-slime-describe-symbol when on the symbol to describe.

Comment: Ah of course it solves the issue! Apologies, I just got confused :)